# Image is not being rendered in my Rails 5 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have upgraded from Rails 2.x.x to 5.0.3 application . I am facing a strange 
  issue while rendering images that are generated from a web service running on 
  another server . When I check the rails log , images are being delivered 
  successfully from the web service with 200 OK status . And also in the network 
  tab of the browser I can see the images with icons . But the same image is not 
  visible on the page . These images are being served by a controller and action 
  Below is the code ;

```
data = open(url)
data_type = data.content_type
send_data(data.read, :type=>data.content_type, :disposition => 'inline')
```

url in the above code is a web 
   service url that generates the image dynamically with the help of controller

This image doesn't exist on the current server but the URL that is 
  finally served has the domain of current server not the actual web service 
  URL .

If I am hitting this URL manually , it is not visible . But If I hit the 
   actual web service URL , image is perfectly loading .

Am I missing anything . Any help would be greatly appreciated .

Comment: You should start by updgrading your syntax, type: date.content_type, disposition: inline

Comment: can you show how do you try to display your img in your view please ?

Comment: Thanks for your response Che .
The code that is rendering the image in the view is below ;

 <%=image_tag(appit_app_report_image_path(:item_id=>item.id,:start_date=>params[:start_date],:end_date=>params[:end_date],:format=>:png),:class=>'graph',:alt=>item.name)%>

Let me know if you need any other information .